# my Launchbad broken after installing cDock

Tags: big-sur, launchpad

I am using MacOS Big Sur 11.3 Beta (20E5217a)

after installing cDock and putting into Apps folder and then running it, my LaunchPad turned to like the image below[image: broken dashboard]

it only contains 4 items on each page

i tried things below:

- dragging them into grid
- uninstalling with AppCleaner and reboot,
- changing screen resolution
- using commands below to restart launchpad

```
defaults write com.apple.dock ResetLaunchPad -bool true; killall Dock
```

non of them worked

Comment: That looks like Launchpad not Dashboard. You also appear to have 20 or more screens, presumably each with a few more apps

Comment: Also, as it seems to be related to cDock: Did you [reach out to the developer](https://www.macenhance.com/contact.html) yet?

Comment: now i sent mail to developer

Comment: @nohillside contacting with developer worked fine

Comment: If contacting the developer helped, could you please post the actual solution as an answer below?